# Combination of $+$ and $-$ for sign-alternating sums

Tags: combinatorics

I need to know quantity of two types of combinations - reflecting and inverse (concerning the center). Reflecting mean, that if first is $+$, then last is $+$, and if second is $-$, then penultimate is $-$, and so on. Inverse mean, that if first is $+$, then last is $-$, and if second is $-$, then penultimate is $+$, and so on. For example:

2) $+-=-+$ (inverse)

4) $+--+=-++-$ (reflecting), $++--=--++$, $+-+-=-+-+$ (inverse)

But $+-+-$ is special case of 2, so we exclude it. For better understanding:

$++=++++=++++++=\cdots$

$+-=+-+-=+-+-+-=\cdots$

$++--=++--++--=++--++--++--=\cdots$

6) $++--++=--++--$, $+-++-+=-+--+-$, $+----+=-++++-$ (reflecting)

$+++---=---+++$, $++-+--=--+-++$, $+-+-+-=-+-+-+$, $+--++-=-++--+$ (inverse)

Here $+-+-+-$ is also special case of 2.

So if $q(m)$ - quantity of combinations (reflecting and inverse), not including special cases,
$$q(2)=1, q(4)=2, q(6)=6$$
But that doesn't mean, that $q(m)=(m/2)!$

Also with special cases their quantity equal to
$$\frac{2^n-2}{2}$$
for reflecting and
$$\frac{2^n}{2}$$
for inverse, so summary quantity equal to $2^n-1$.

How can I calculate their quantity (without special cases)?

Comment: I roughly see what you mean, but I think you should try to make it more formal, right now it is quite difficult to understand your question. Maybe you could define a set with operations on it and/or equivalence relations and state precisely what you consider to be "special cases".

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, thank you for answer! I made necessary corrections.

Comment: Thanks. I still have trouble seeing why there is no consideration for $++$ in the case 2).

Comment: There is no sign-alternating, only $++$ or $--$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, have you got any ideas how to solve it? I sure it simple.